# Make Meteor.methods Synchronous and Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

Sometimes I need the Meteor.call to `writeMeLater` to be queued and executed synchronously(block other calls to `writeMeLater` from the same client).

Other times the calls to `writeMeLater` should be executed as soon as possible without queueing up behind all the calls currently queued.

Below is my attempt by using `this.unblock()` if a `async` parameter is true. Cases 1 and 2 works fine. But in Case 3, calls with `async=true` is being queued behind calls with `async=false`! How can we make calls with `async=true` skip the queue? This will be similar to how calls from a second client are not queued after calls from the first client,

*All `Meteor.call()` are made from client*

**Case 1 (correctly synchronous):**

```
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)
```

**Case 2 (correctly asynchronous):**

```
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
```

**Case 3 (not the desired behavior)**

```
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 's', false)

Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
Meteor.call('writeMeLater', 'a', true)
```

**server/main.js**

```
writeMeLater = function(data, callback) {
    console.log('writeMeLater: ', data)

    // simulate taking 3 second to complete
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        Logs.insert({data: data, timestamp: new Date().getTime()})
        console.log('Log.insert: ', data)
        callback(null, 'done')
    }, 3 * 1000)
}



writeMeLaterSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(writeMeLater)



Meteor.methods({

    writeMeLater: function(data, async) {
        if(async)
            this.unblock()

        writeMeLaterSync(data)
    }

})
```

Comment: @imslavko Is it possible to have the some of the method calls be executed immediately rather than queued, similar to how method calls from a different client are not queued behind the calls from the first client

Comment: that's exactly what `this.unblock()` call will do - it will allow another method call for the current connection to *start* before the previous is done. That's the output I see: http://pastebin.com/gtdgLTGf and it looks correct to me. For 3 synchronous calls there is a 3s delay before the call finishes. For the second batch - they all start at the same time and end after 3 secs.

Comment: Since you are running only one node.js server, all 6 calls will share the same event-loop. Remember, node.js is single-threaded. There is no real multithreading, only cooperative concurrency

Comment: for the real multithreading you would need to run several server instances and load balance the connections load between them, but even with that, one DDP connection will be talking only to one single-threaded server (as DDP is stateful)

Comment: @imslavko I'm hoping for a output like http://pastebin.com/HHeg14ij . When the second batch of functions are called, they do not queue up behind the first batch of function calls. This is how it will work if the second batch of function calls are made by a second client. Can it be done if both batches of function calls are made by the same client?

Comment: only if client establishes two different DDP connections or you have a Message Queue on your server and multiple processes of node.js servers. That's just the limitation of single-threaded JavaScript environment.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is, why not actually *create a queue?* Instead of relying on the JavaScript event loop as your queue. Then insert documents into that queue, like:

```
WritesQueue = new Meteor.Collection("WritesQueue");
WritesQueue.insert({data: 'a', prioritize: true, inserted: new Date()});
```

And maybe every time you insert a high-priority write, trigger `Meteor.call("write")` which processes the queue, with the prioritized (non-async) ones going first:

```
Meteor.methods({
  write: function () {
    WritesQueue.find({prioritize: true}, {sort: {inserted: 1}})
    .forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.data);
      WritesQueue.remove(doc._id);
    });
    WritesQueue.find({prioritize: false}, {sort: {inserted: 1}})
    .forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.data);
      WritesQueue.remove(doc._id);
    });
  }
});
```

Or if you want the queue processed every time you insert a high- or low-priority write, either call the `write` method either time or put the `insert` inside the `write` method itself. This solves the jump-to-the-head-of-the-line problem, though the writes are still processed synchronously per client.

As for trying to achieve parallel processing for a single client, @imslavko (in the comments to the question, above) is correct, in that one way to achieve this is for the client to establish multiple DDP connections. There's a relatively simple, albeit hacky and non-Meteoric, way to do that:

Install [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) and in your server code, define a server-side route:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('writeMeLater', {
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
      Meteor.call('writeMeLater',
        this.request.query.data, this.request.query.async);
    }
  });
});
```

The `this.request.query` above is an object with key-value pairs that you submitted with the request. For example:

```
HTTP.post("http://yoursite.com/writeMeLater",
  {params: {data: 'a', async: true}});
```

As far as the server knows, this request is coming from a new client, so it will be processed in a new Fiber (i.e. thread). If the `writeMeLater` method knows not to wait, many instances of it can start running concurrently. Now the issue becomes keeping the requests in order, if it's important to you that the order of execution on the server is the same as on the client, since the HTTP POST requests might not necessarily arrive at the server in the same order as they were sent. But there are various ways of dealing with that too (send them in batches, or include a counter and have the server wait a few seconds if it detects a request out of sequence, etc.).